Is there a way to exclude a nested folder from tsconfig.json?
I was forced to move a project with one set of compiler settings inside another project with different settings. I want to add a nested tsconfig to configure compilation specifically for the folder with the moved project and exclude this folder from the global tsconfig.
But I can’t manage to exclude the necessary folder from the global configuration. Here’s the original config.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["vite/client", "vitest/globals"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/shared/ui/components/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["src/shared/ui/styles/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"],
  
>! "references": [{
>!     "path": "src/features/GIS/tsconfig.json"
>!   }]
}

Adding different variations of the path to the folder to exclude prop doesn’t work, such as src/features/GIS src/features/GIS/, src/features/GIS/**/*.ts vue-tsc is being used as the compiler.
Can I get possible ways to do this better
